# Convergence of these series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2nx^{n}}{(n+1)^{2}3^{n}} \tag{1}$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n}\tan\frac{x}{4^{n}}\tag{2}$$

Is there any good article that describes an equivalents like if $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \sin\frac{2\pi}{3^{n}} \sim \frac{2\pi}{3^{n}}\tag{3}$$

(am I right about $(3)$?)

Comment: so what is precisly your question? are you looking for a way to show convergence of the two first series , or/and you want to know if $\lim_{x\to\infty} \sin\frac{2\pi}{3^{n}} \sim \frac{2\pi}{3^{n}}\tag{3}$

Comment: Do you mean $n \rightarrow \infty $ instead of $x$ ?

Comment: @беркай I edited that for him/her a minute ago, waiting for it to approved.

Comment: I am a newbie, seems like @user10444 already edited this question for me. I want to help me in solving this equations, or better give me a link to a good article that describes tips and tricks in solving this equations.

Comment: @wsevendays Have you tried applying the ratio test for the first series?

Comment: @user10444 is it? If yes, I don't know how to shorten it, $$ \frac{2(n+1)x^{n+1}(n+1)^{2}3^{n}}{(n+2)^{2}3^{n+1}2nx^{n}}$$

Comment: You get $\frac{(n+1)^3 x}{3(n+2)^2n}$ so taking $\frac 1 3 x$ outside the limit since it independent of n you get $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(n+1)^3}{n(n+2)^2} = 1$ since its the limit of polynomials of the same degree. Can you continue?

Comment: @user10444  Yes, I understand everything you said. So $$|\frac{1}{3}x| < 1$$ must be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assertion
$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} \sin\frac{2\pi}{3^{n}} \sim \frac{2\pi}{3^{n}}$$
is perhaps not precise enough for our needs. But it can be made precise, in a form useful for Ratio Test calculations.

We have 
$$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin t}{t}=1.$$
We can replace $\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{3^n}\right)$ by 
$$\frac{\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{3^n}\right)}{\frac{2\pi}{3^n}}\frac{2\pi}{3^n}.$$
The first term goes safely to $1$, while $\frac{2\pi}{3^n}$ "plays nicely" with the Ratio Test.

We can do precisely the same thing with $\tan\left(\frac{x}{4^n}\right)$ for $x\ne 0$.  Since 
$$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\tan t}{t}=1,$$ 
use
$$\frac{\tan\left(\frac{x}{4^n}\right)}{\frac{x}{4^n}}\frac{x}{4^n}$$
in the Ratio Test limit calculation. The front part has limit $1$, so it ford not affect the Ratio Test limit.

**Remark:** More informally, we can simply *replace* $\tan(x/4^n)$ by $x/4^n$. However, that is likely to be considered too informal in a homework problem when an important  focus of the course is careful justification. Later, when one is doing "real" work, we can be more casual, for we *know* that formal detail *could* be supplied.

In answer to an earlier comment of yours, $\cos x$ is nearly $1$ if $x$ is close to $0$. But it can be useful to know that since the first $2$ terms of the power series of $\cos x$ are $1-\frac{x^2}{2}$, near $0$ the function $1-\cos x$ behaves like $\frac{x^2}{2}$.

Comment: Thanks, I can now understand Ratio Test more deeply

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sin\frac{2\pi}{3^{n}} \sim \frac{2\pi}{3^{n}}\tag{3}$ Is correct since $\lim_{x\to 0 }  \dfrac{sinx}{x}=1$ and since sinus is continuous this holds for any sequence 
 ${x_n\to 0}$

Comment: Is this rule correct for tan/cos?

Comment: maybe this article could be usefull : http://math.uchicago.edu/~vipul/teaching-1011/152/trigonometriclimitsandderivatives.pdf